# Integer subclass hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I have a couple `int` child classes that represent different ranges. Some of their behavior is shared in an abstract class and I want them to be comparable among themselves and with plain integers but not with other different ranges. Hashing stays the same as integers, so there will be collisions, but I thought that wasn't an issue as an equality check will be performed to solve the hash collision.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Range(int, ABC):
    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def min(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def max(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # Check the lower and upper bounds
        if not (self.min <= self <= self.max):
            raise ValueError

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # If they are a range but not the same one just return False
        if isinstance(other, Range) and not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return False
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        # If they are a range but not the same one just return True
        if isinstance(other, Range) and not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return True
        return NotImplemented

    def _check_other(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Range) and not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            raise NotImplementedError

    def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
        self._check_other(other)
        return int(self) < int(other)

    def __le__(self, other) -> bool:
        self._check_other(other)
        return int(self) <= int(other)

    def __gt__(self, other) -> bool:
        self._check_other(other)
        return int(self) > int(other)

    def __ge__(self, other) -> bool:
        self._check_other(other)
        return int(self) >= int(other)

    __hash__ = int.__hash__


class Range20(Range):
    min = 1
    max = 20


class Range100(Range):
    min = 1
    max = 100


m = {
    Range20(1): -1,
    Range20(2): -2,
    Range100(1): 1,
    Range100(2): 2,
}

assert Range20(1) == 1, "Range20(1) != 1"
assert Range20(1) != 2, "Range20(1) == 2"
assert Range20(1) == Range20(1), "Range20(1) != Range20(1)"
assert Range20(1) != Range20(2), "Range20(1) == Range20(2)"
assert Range20(1) != Range100(1), "Range20(1) == Range100(1)"
assert not (Range20(1) == Range100(1)), "Range20(1) == Range100(1) bis"
assert Range20(2) > 1, "Range20(2) <= 1"
assert Range20(2) >= 2, "Range20(2) < 2"
assert Range20(2) < 3, "Range20(2) >= 3"
assert Range20(2) <= 2, "Range20(2) > 2"
assert Range20(2) > Range20(1), "Range20(2) <= Range20(1)"
assert Range20(2) >= Range20(2), "Range20(2) < Range20(2)"
assert Range20(2) < Range20(3), "Range20(2) >= Range20(3)"
assert Range20(2) <= Range20(2), "Range20(2) > Range20(2)"
assert hash(Range20(1)) == hash(1), "hash(Range20(1)) != hash(1)"
assert hash(Range20(1)) == hash(Range100(1)), "hash(Range20(1)) != hash(Range100(1))"
assert Range20(1) in m, "Range20(1) not in m"
assert Range100(1) in m, "Range100(1) not in m"
assert 1 not in m, "1 in m"
```

All assertions should pass but some aren't passing right now. The last assertion may be hard to achieve as they are considered to be equal by `__eq__` so not passing that one would be fine, but the previous two need to pass so that `m[Range20(1)] == -1` and `m[Range100(1)] == 1` (i.e., I can access the values in the map).

Edit: added comparisson methods and assertions but the result is still the same
Edit 2: added additional assertions

Answer (score 1):

Changing this part here works with me (except assertion 17 fails -- which it doesn't actually align with i.e. the previous equality tests, unless you are wishing for something else I missed in your question):

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    # If they are a range but not the same one just return False
    if isinstance(other, Range) and not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return False
    elif isinstance(other, Range) and isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return True
    return NotImplemented

def __ne__(self, other):
    # If they are a range but not the same one just return True
    if isinstance(other, Range) and not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return True
    elif isinstance(other, Range) and isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return False

    return NotImplemented
```

Comment: That actually would make `assert Range20(1) == Range20(2)` pass and I don't want that to happen. Thought I had added enough assertions but seems like I haven't. However your answer gave me an idea, I will come back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

@MoeNeuron guided me in the right direction, by adding some additional asserts I discovered that `assert Range20(1) == Range20(1)` was failing. I thought that by returning `NotImplemented` the int method would be able to handle those cases but it seems it doesn't. The solution is to use the following two modified methods:

```py
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Range):
            if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
                # If they are a range element but not from the same range
                return False
            # If they are a range element from the same range
            return int(self) == int(other)
        # If they are not a range element delegate to int
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Range):
            if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
                # If they are a range element but not from the same range
                return True
            # If they are a range element from the same range
            return int(self) != int(other)
        # If they are not a range element delegate to int
        return NotImplemented
```

With these modified methods, only the last assertion fails, which is acceptable as I said in the question.